# Background image transparency in DIV

Tags: css, background-image, transparency

I'm trying to make a background image transparent (no option to make a transparent PNG or lighter image, the images are changed often).

```
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
opacity: 0.2;
```

Got the image is working, but everything inside the DIV is transparent too. I've searched for a solution, but can't seem to implement the right one. Any pointer on how to fix that?

Comment: set for `container:     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` and clear opacity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use opacity on the background div inside of the wrapper element.

```css
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.page::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:  url('http://www.visitnorwich.co.uk/assets/Uploads/Events-images/Theatre-generic.jpg');
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box {
  display: inline;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  My page
  <div class="box">Red box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had to use
`z-index: -0;`
to make it work... but it did the job! Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use CSS [`linear-gradient()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) with [`rgba()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors).

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url("https://i.imgur.com/xnh5x47.jpg");
}
span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Hello world.</span></div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un26w5rx/)**

*Explanation:*

- The first part: `linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5))` creates a semi-transparent white background color. You can change the alpha parameter as needed between `0` (fully transparent) and `1` (fully opaque).
- The second part: `url("https://i.imgur.com/xnh5x47.jpg")` is to display the actual background image.
- Together: `background: linear-gradient(...), url(...);` creates multiple backgrounds, two of them are stacked, the first one covers the second.

Comment: Doesn't that just make the white above the image transparent ?

Comment: Does this put more, or less stress on the browser rendering?

Comment: @JanTeunis I don't think anything will be noticeable, as it's pretty standard CSS3 stuff, you can do some tests if you want. Learn more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds).

Comment: @Ced That's correct, but it's actually white with some transparency, and it's exactly what the question is asking for, of course you can change it to a dark color as needed.

Comment: Who knows what OP has behind his image, it might not be plain blank (it could be another image). It's useful in any case I agree and instructive nonetheless. Upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo elem

```css
    div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      color: green;
      position: relative;
    }

    div:before{
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/xnh5x47.jpg);
        content: "";
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.5;
        top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
        background-size: cover;
     }
```

```html
<div> LOLOLOL </div>
```

Comment: Had to use
`z-index: -0;`
to make it work... but it did the job! Thanks.